# Adding a plot to a DynamicModule

Tags: plotting, dynamic, gui-construction

How can I add a Plot or Plot3D to my DynamicModule (on the same panel) without having a negative impact on the original function? I tried different (for me) logical ways to add the Plot function, but I can't seem to get it work.

```
DynamicModule[{a, asq},
  a = 0;
  asq[]:= a*a;
  Deploy[
    Style[
      Panel[
        Grid[
          Transpose[
            {{Style["Input number", Blue], Style["Square of number",Red]},
             {InputField[Dynamic[a], Number], 
              InputField[Dynamic[asq[]], Enabled -> False,Background ->Red]}}],
          Alignment -> Left],
          ImageMargins -> 10], 
      DefaultOptions -> 
       {InputField -> {ContinuousAction -> True, FieldSize -> {{5,30}, {1, Infinity}}}}]]]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: What do you want to plot?

Comment: InputField is a bit tricky to use.  May I suggest a manipulate?  `asq[b_] := b*b; Manipulate[
 Grid[{{ListLinePlot[{a, asq[a]}], 
    Framed[Style[asq[a], Red], Background -> LightRed]}}], {a, 1, 10, 
  1}, ControlType -> Slider] `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are working too hard. If you just want to put a plot below your input fields, you can do it like this.

```
asq[a_] := a*a

DynamicModule[{a = 2},
  Style[
    Panel[Dynamic @
      Column[{
        Grid[{
          {Style["Input number", Blue], InputField[Dynamic[a], Number]}, 
          {Style["Square of number", Red], 
           InputField[Dynamic[asq[a]], Enabled -> False, Background -> Red]}},
          Alignment -> Left],
        Plot[asq[x], {x, 0, a}]}],
      ImageMargins -> 10], 
    DefaultOptions -> 
      {InputField -> {ContinuousAction -> True, FieldSize -> {{5, 30}, {1, Infinity}}}}]]
```

[image: panel]